# Prove the sequence $a_n=n^n/n!$ is increasing and not bounded above

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that the sequence $a_n=n^n/n!$ for $n\geqslant1$ is increasing and not bounded above.

I got the increasing part, but I don't know how to show that it is not bounded above

Comment: Show $a_{n+1}/a_{n}\geq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider looking at the ratio $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} $$ and show that this quantity is greater than one for all $n$.  So,
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} =\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}n!}{(n+1)!n^n}$$
Try canceling as much as you can and see what happens.

Comment: I see why it is increasing, but how do I show it is not bounded above?

Comment: If you show strict inequality then the sequence can't be bounded above.

Comment: A sequence can be strictly increasing but bounded.

Comment: Ah!  Yes, that was a stupid comment on my part.  May the Gods of Math forgive.

Answer (score 2):

$a_{n+1} = (n+1)^{n+1}/(n+1)! = \frac{(n+1)(n+1)^{n}}{(n+1)n!} = \frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n!} > \frac{n^n}{n!} = a_n$ for $n \geqslant 1 $

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\frac{n^n}{n!} = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n}{k} = n \prod_{k=2}^{n} \frac{n}{k}> n.$$

Hence the sequence is unbounded.